# long query execution time for Percona 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I have a query:

```
UPDATE offers AS t
            JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM `offers`
                    WHERE source_id = (SELECT id FROM sources
                             WHERE `name` = \'A\')
                    AND `deleted_at` IS NULL) t2
                ON t.name = t2.name
            SET t.deleted_at = NOW()
            WHERE
                t.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND
                t.source_id = (SELECT id FROM sources WHERE `name` = \'B\')
```

Table :
Id / name / source_id / timestamps

during testing on a local machine, it executed quickly on Mysql 8. When I deploy the project, Percona 5.7 appeared on the production server. And now, on the production server, this query is simply incredibly long. more then 10 min on 200k rows. the project uses INNODB on both servers.

On my localhost i have default Mysql 8 config, OS WIN10PRO

and this is **production** configuration:

```
"auto_generate_certs"   "ON"
"auto_increment_increment"  "1"
"auto_increment_offset" "1"
"autocommit"    "ON"
"automatic_sp_privileges"   "ON"
"avoid_temporal_upgrade"    "OFF"
"back_log"  "58"
"basedir"   "/usr/"
"big_tables"    "OFF"
"bind_address"  "*"
"binlog_cache_size" "32768"
"binlog_checksum"   "CRC32"
"binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates"   "OFF"
"binlog_error_action"   "ABORT_SERVER"
"binlog_format" "ROW"
"binlog_group_commit_sync_delay"    "0"
"binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count"   "0"
"binlog_gtid_simple_recovery"   "ON"
"binlog_max_flush_queue_time"   "0"
"binlog_order_commits"  "ON"
"binlog_row_image"  "FULL"
"binlog_rows_query_log_events"  "OFF"
"binlog_skip_flush_commands"    "OFF"
"binlog_space_limit"    "0"
"binlog_stmt_cache_size"    "32768"
"binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size"    "25000"
"binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking"    "COMMIT_ORDER"
"block_encryption_mode" "aes-128-ecb"
"bulk_insert_buffer_size"   "2097152"
"character_set_client"  "utf8"
"character_set_connection"  "utf8"
"character_set_database"    "utf8"
"character_set_filesystem"  "binary"
"character_set_results" "utf8"
"character_set_server"  "utf8"
"character_set_system"  "utf8"
"character_sets_dir"    "/usr/share/percona-server/charsets/"
"check_proxy_users" "OFF"
"collation_connection"  "utf8_unicode_ci"
"collation_database"    "utf8_unicode_ci"
"collation_server"  "utf8_unicode_ci"
"completion_type"   "NO_CHAIN"
"concurrent_insert" "AUTO"
"connect_timeout"   "10"
"core_file" "OFF"
"csv_mode"  ""
"datadir"   "/var/lib/mysql/"
"date_format"   "%Y-%m-%d"
"datetime_format"   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"
"default_authentication_plugin" "mysql_native_password"
"default_password_lifetime" "0"
"default_storage_engine"    "InnoDB"
"default_tmp_storage_engine"    "InnoDB"
"default_week_format"   "0"
"delay_key_write"   "ON"
"delayed_insert_limit"  "100"
"delayed_insert_timeout"    "300"
"delayed_queue_size"    "1000"
"disabled_storage_engines"  ""
"disconnect_on_expired_password"    "ON"
"div_precision_increment"   "4"
"encrypt_binlog"    "OFF"
"encrypt_tmp_files" "OFF"
"end_markers_in_json"   "OFF"
"enforce_gtid_consistency"  "OFF"
"enforce_storage_engine"    ""
"eq_range_index_dive_limit" "200"
"event_scheduler"   "OFF"
"expand_fast_index_creation"    "OFF"
"expire_logs_days"  "10"
"explicit_defaults_for_timestamp"   "ON"
"extra_max_connections" "1"
"extra_port"    "0"
"flush" "OFF"
"flush_time"    "0"
"foreign_key_checks"    "ON"
"ft_boolean_syntax" "+ -><()~*:""""&|"
"ft_max_word_len"   "84"
"ft_min_word_len"   "4"
"ft_query_expansion_limit"  "20"
"ft_query_extra_word_chars" "OFF"
"ft_stopword_file"  "(built-in)"
"general_log"   "OFF"
"general_log_file"  "/var/lib/mysql/log.log"
"group_concat_max_len"  "1024"
"gtid_executed" ""
"gtid_executed_compression_period"  "1000"
"gtid_mode" "OFF"
"gtid_owned"    ""
"gtid_purged"   ""
"have_backup_locks" "YES"
"have_backup_safe_binlog_info"  "YES"
"have_compress" "YES"
"have_crypt"    "YES"
"have_dynamic_loading"  "YES"
"have_geometry" "YES"
"have_openssl"  "YES"
"have_profiling"    "YES"
"have_query_cache"  "YES"
"have_rtree_keys"   "YES"
"have_snapshot_cloning" "YES"
"have_ssl"  "YES"
"have_statement_timeout"    "YES"
"have_symlink"  "YES"
"host_cache_size"   "171"
"ignore_builtin_innodb" "OFF"
"ignore_db_dirs"    ""
"init_connect"  "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
"init_file" ""
"init_slave"    ""
"innodb_adaptive_flushing"  "ON"
"innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm"  "10"
"innodb_adaptive_hash_index"    "ON"
"innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts"  "8"
"innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay"   "150000"
"innodb_api_bk_commit_interval" "5"
"innodb_api_disable_rowlock"    "OFF"
"innodb_api_enable_binlog"  "OFF"
"innodb_api_enable_mdl" "OFF"
"innodb_api_trx_level"  "0"
"innodb_autoextend_increment"   "64"
"innodb_autoinc_lock_mode"  "1"
"innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval"   "3600"
"innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed"   "OFF"
"innodb_background_scrub_data_interval" "604800"
"innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed" "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size" "134217728"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown"   "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now"   "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct"   "25"
"innodb_buffer_pool_filename"   "ib_buffer_pool"
"innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file"   "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_instances"  "8"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort" "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup"    "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_now"   "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_size"   "1073741824"
"innodb_change_buffer_max_size" "25"
"innodb_change_buffering"   "all"
"innodb_checksum_algorithm" "crc32"
"innodb_checksums"  "ON"
"innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor" "high_checkpoint"
"innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled"  "OFF"
"innodb_commit_concurrency" "0"
"innodb_compressed_columns_threshold"   "96"
"innodb_compressed_columns_zip_level"   "6"
"innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct"  "5"
"innodb_compression_level"  "6"
"innodb_compression_pad_pct_max"    "50"
"innodb_concurrency_tickets"    "5000"
"innodb_corrupt_table_action"   "assert"
"innodb_data_file_path" "ibdata1:12M:autoextend"
"innodb_data_home_dir"  ""
"innodb_deadlock_detect"    "ON"
"innodb_default_encryption_key_id"  "0"
"innodb_default_row_format" "dynamic"
"innodb_disable_sort_file_cache"    "OFF"
"innodb_doublewrite"    "ON"
"innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm"  "backoff"
"innodb_encrypt_online_alter_logs"  "OFF"
"innodb_encrypt_tables" "OFF"
"innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age"  "1"
"innodb_encryption_rotation_iops"   "100"
"innodb_encryption_threads" "0"
"innodb_fast_shutdown"  "1"
"innodb_file_format"    "Barracuda"
"innodb_file_format_check"  "ON"
"innodb_file_format_max"    "Barracuda"
"innodb_file_per_table" "ON"
"innodb_fill_factor"    "100"
"innodb_flush_log_at_timeout"   "1"
"innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit"    "2"
"innodb_flush_method"   "O_DIRECT"
"innodb_flush_neighbors"    "1"
"innodb_flush_sync" "ON"
"innodb_flushing_avg_loops" "30"
"innodb_force_index_records_in_range"   "0"
"innodb_force_load_corrupted"   "OFF"
"innodb_force_recovery" "0"
"innodb_ft_aux_table"   ""
"innodb_ft_cache_size"  "8000000"
"innodb_ft_enable_diag_print"   "OFF"
"innodb_ft_enable_stopword" "ON"
"innodb_ft_ignore_stopwords"    "OFF"
"innodb_ft_max_token_size"  "84"
"innodb_ft_min_token_size"  "3"
"innodb_ft_num_word_optimize"   "2000"
"innodb_ft_result_cache_limit"  "2000000000"
"innodb_ft_server_stopword_table"   ""
"innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree" "2"
"innodb_ft_total_cache_size"    "640000000"
"innodb_ft_user_stopword_table" ""
"innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed"  "OFF"
"innodb_io_capacity"    "200"
"innodb_io_capacity_max"    "2000"
"innodb_kill_idle_transaction"  "0"
"innodb_large_prefix"   "ON"
"innodb_lock_wait_timeout"  "50"
"innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog"    "OFF"
"innodb_log_buffer_size"    "16777216"
"innodb_log_checksums"  "ON"
"innodb_log_compressed_pages"   "ON"
"innodb_log_file_size"  "67108864"
"innodb_log_files_in_group" "2"
"innodb_log_group_home_dir" "./"
"innodb_log_write_ahead_size"   "8192"
"innodb_lru_scan_depth" "1024"
"innodb_max_bitmap_file_size"   "104857600"
"innodb_max_changed_pages"  "1000000"
"innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct"    "75.000000"
"innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm"    "0.000000"
"innodb_max_purge_lag"  "0"
"innodb_max_purge_lag_delay"    "0"
"innodb_max_undo_log_size"  "1073741824"
"innodb_monitor_disable"    ""
"innodb_monitor_enable" ""
"innodb_monitor_reset"  ""
"innodb_monitor_reset_all"  ""
"innodb_numa_interleave"    "OFF"
"innodb_old_blocks_pct" "37"
"innodb_old_blocks_time"    "1000"
"innodb_online_alter_log_max_size"  "134217728"
"innodb_open_files" "2473"
"innodb_optimize_fulltext_only" "OFF"
"innodb_page_cleaners"  "4"
"innodb_page_size"  "16384"
"innodb_parallel_dblwr_encrypt" "OFF"
"innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path"  "xb_doublewrite"
"innodb_print_all_deadlocks"    "OFF"
"innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info"   "OFF"
"innodb_purge_batch_size"   "300"
"innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency"  "128"
"innodb_purge_threads"  "4"
"innodb_random_read_ahead"  "OFF"
"innodb_read_ahead_threshold"   "56"
"innodb_read_io_threads"    "4"
"innodb_read_only"  "OFF"
"innodb_records_in_range"   "0"
"innodb_redo_log_encrypt"   "OFF"
"innodb_replication_delay"  "0"
"innodb_rollback_on_timeout"    "OFF"
"innodb_rollback_segments"  "128"
"innodb_scrub_log"  "OFF"
"innodb_scrub_log_speed"    "256"
"innodb_show_locks_held"    "10"
"innodb_show_verbose_locks" "0"
"innodb_sort_buffer_size"   "1048576"
"innodb_spin_wait_delay"    "6"
"innodb_stats_auto_recalc"  "ON"
"innodb_stats_include_delete_marked"    "OFF"
"innodb_stats_method"   "nulls_equal"
"innodb_stats_on_metadata"  "OFF"
"innodb_stats_persistent"   "ON"
"innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages"  "20"
"innodb_stats_sample_pages" "8"
"innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages"   "8"
"innodb_status_output"  "OFF"
"innodb_status_output_locks"    "OFF"
"innodb_strict_mode"    "OFF"
"innodb_support_xa" "ON"
"innodb_sync_array_size"    "1"
"innodb_sync_spin_loops"    "30"
"innodb_sys_tablespace_encrypt" "OFF"
"innodb_table_locks"    "ON"
"innodb_temp_data_file_path"    "ibtmp1:12M:autoextend"
"innodb_temp_tablespace_encrypt"    "OFF"
"innodb_thread_concurrency" "0"
"innodb_thread_sleep_delay" "10000"
"innodb_tmpdir" ""
"innodb_track_changed_pages"    "OFF"
"innodb_undo_directory" "./"
"innodb_undo_log_encrypt"   "OFF"
"innodb_undo_log_truncate"  "OFF"
"innodb_undo_logs"  "128"
"innodb_undo_tablespaces"   "0"
"innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit" "ON"
"innodb_use_native_aio" "ON"
"innodb_version"    "5.7.34-37"
"innodb_write_io_threads"   "4"
"interactive_timeout"   "28800"
"internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine"  "InnoDB"
"join_buffer_size"  "8388608"
"keep_files_on_create"  "OFF"
"key_buffer_size"   "50331648"
"key_cache_age_threshold"   "300"
"key_cache_block_size"  "1024"
"key_cache_division_limit"  "100"
"keyring_operations"    "ON"
"kill_idle_transaction" "0"
"large_files_support"   "ON"
"large_page_size"   "0"
"large_pages"   "OFF"
"lc_messages"   "en_US"
"lc_messages_dir"   "/usr/share/percona-server/"
"lc_time_names" "en_US"
"license"   "GPL"
"local_infile"  "ON"
"lock_wait_timeout" "31536000"
"locked_in_memory"  "OFF"
"log_bin"   "OFF"
"log_bin_basename"  ""
"log_bin_index" ""
"log_bin_trust_function_creators"   "OFF"
"log_bin_use_v1_row_events" "OFF"
"log_builtin_as_identified_by_password" "OFF"
"log_error" "/var/log/mysql/error.log"
"log_error_verbosity"   "3"
"log_output"    "FILE"
"log_queries_not_using_indexes" "OFF"
"log_slave_updates" "OFF"
"log_slow_admin_statements" "OFF"
"log_slow_filter"   ""
"log_slow_rate_limit"   "1"
"log_slow_rate_type"    "session"
"log_slow_slave_statements" "OFF"
"log_slow_sp_statements"    "ON"
"log_slow_verbosity"    ""
"log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog"  "ON"
"log_syslog"    "OFF"
"log_syslog_facility"   "daemon"
"log_syslog_include_pid"    "ON"
"log_syslog_tag"    ""
"log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes"    "0"
"log_timestamps"    "UTC"
"log_warnings"  "2"
"long_query_time"   "10.000000"
"low_priority_updates"  "OFF"
"lower_case_file_system"    "OFF"
"lower_case_table_names"    "0"
"master_info_repository"    "FILE"
"master_verify_checksum"    "OFF"
"max_allowed_packet"    "16777216"
"max_binlog_cache_size" "18446744073709547520"
"max_binlog_files"  "0"
"max_binlog_size"   "104857600"
"max_binlog_stmt_cache_size"    "18446744073709547520"
"max_connect_errors"    "100"
"max_connections"   "43"
"max_delayed_threads"   "20"
"max_digest_length" "1024"
"max_error_count"   "64"
"max_execution_time"    "0"
"max_heap_table_size"   "134217728"
"max_insert_delayed_threads"    "20"
"max_join_size" "18446744073709551615"
"max_length_for_sort_data"  "1024"
"max_points_in_geometry"    "65536"
"max_prepared_stmt_count"   "16382"
"max_relay_log_size"    "0"
"max_seeks_for_key" "18446744073709551615"
"max_slowlog_files" "0"
"max_slowlog_size"  "0"
"max_sort_length"   "1024"
"max_sp_recursion_depth"    "0"
"max_tmp_tables"    "32"
"max_user_connections"  "0"
"max_write_lock_count"  "18446744073709551615"
"metadata_locks_cache_size" "1024"
"metadata_locks_hash_instances" "8"
"min_examined_row_limit"    "0"
"multi_range_count" "256"
"myisam_data_pointer_size"  "6"
"myisam_max_sort_file_size" "9223372036853727232"
"myisam_mmap_size"  "18446744073709551615"
"myisam_recover_options"    "BACKUP"
"myisam_repair_threads" "1"
"myisam_sort_buffer_size"   "8388608"
"myisam_stats_method"   "nulls_unequal"
"myisam_use_mmap"   "OFF"
"mysql_native_password_proxy_users" "OFF"
"net_buffer_length" "16384"
"net_read_timeout"  "30"
"net_retry_count"   "10"
"net_write_timeout" "60"
"new"   "OFF"
"ngram_token_size"  "2"
"offline_mode"  "OFF"
"old"   "OFF"
"old_alter_table"   "OFF"
"old_passwords" "0"
"open_files_limit"  "5000"
"optimizer_prune_level" "1"
"optimizer_search_depth"    "62"
"optimizer_switch"  "index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,prefer_ordering_index=on,favor_range_scan=off"
"optimizer_trace"   "enabled=off,one_line=off"
"optimizer_trace_features"  "greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on"
"optimizer_trace_limit" "1"
"optimizer_trace_max_mem_size"  "16384"
"optimizer_trace_offset"    "-1"
"parser_max_mem_size"   "18446744073709551615"
"performance_schema"    "ON"
"performance_schema_accounts_size"  "-1"
"performance_schema_digests_size"   "10000"
"performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size"    "10000"
"performance_schema_events_stages_history_size" "10"
"performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size"    "10000"
"performance_schema_events_statements_history_size" "10"
"performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size"  "10000"
"performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size"   "10"
"performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size" "10000"
"performance_schema_events_waits_history_size"  "10"
"performance_schema_hosts_size" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_cond_classes"   "80"
"performance_schema_max_cond_instances" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_digest_length"  "1024"
"performance_schema_max_file_classes"   "80"
"performance_schema_max_file_handles"   "32768"
"performance_schema_max_file_instances" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_index_stat" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_memory_classes" "400"
"performance_schema_max_metadata_locks" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_mutex_classes"  "250"
"performance_schema_max_mutex_instances"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_program_instances"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes" "50"
"performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_max_socket_classes" "10"
"performance_schema_max_socket_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_max_sql_text_length"    "1024"
"performance_schema_max_stage_classes"  "150"
"performance_schema_max_statement_classes"  "203"
"performance_schema_max_statement_stack"    "10"
"performance_schema_max_table_handles"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_table_instances"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_thread_classes" "50"
"performance_schema_max_thread_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size" "512"
"performance_schema_setup_actors_size"  "-1"
"performance_schema_setup_objects_size" "-1"
"performance_schema_users_size" "-1"
"pid_file"  "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"
"plugin_dir"    "/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/"
"port"  "3306"
"preload_buffer_size"   "32768"
"profiling" "OFF"
"profiling_history_size"    "15"
"protocol_version"  "10"
"proxy_protocol_networks"   ""
"query_alloc_block_size"    "8192"
"query_cache_limit" "16777216"
"query_cache_min_res_unit"  "4096"
"query_cache_size"  "134217728"
"query_cache_strip_comments"    "OFF"
"query_cache_type"  "ON"
"query_cache_wlock_invalidate"  "OFF"
"query_prealloc_size"   "8192"
"range_alloc_block_size"    "4096"
"range_optimizer_max_mem_size"  "8388608"
"rbr_exec_mode" "STRICT"
"read_buffer_size"  "131072"
"read_only" "OFF"
"read_rnd_buffer_size"  "262144"
"replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config" "OFF"
"replication_sender_observe_commit_only"    "OFF"
"report_host"   ""
"report_password"   ""
"report_port"   "3306"
"report_user"   ""
"require_secure_transport"  "OFF"
"rpl_stop_slave_timeout"    "31536000"
"secure_auth"   "ON"
"secure_file_priv"  "/var/lib/mysql-files/"
"server_id" "0"
"server_id_bits"    "32"
"session_track_gtids"   "OFF"
"session_track_schema"  "ON"
"session_track_state_change"    "OFF"
"session_track_system_variables"    "time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection"
"session_track_transaction_info"    "OFF"
"show_compatibility_56" "OFF"
"show_create_table_verbosity"   "OFF"
"show_old_temporals"    "OFF"
"skip_external_locking" "ON"
"skip_name_resolve" "ON"
"skip_networking"   "OFF"
"skip_show_database"    "OFF"
"slave_allow_batching"  "OFF"
"slave_checkpoint_group"    "512"
"slave_checkpoint_period"   "300"
"slave_compressed_protocol" "OFF"
"slave_exec_mode"   "STRICT"
"slave_load_tmpdir" "/tmp"
"slave_max_allowed_packet"  "1073741824"
"slave_net_timeout" "60"
"slave_parallel_type"   "DATABASE"
"slave_parallel_workers"    "0"
"slave_pending_jobs_size_max"   "16777216"
"slave_preserve_commit_order"   "OFF"
"slave_rows_search_algorithms"  "TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN"
"slave_skip_errors" "OFF"
"slave_sql_verify_checksum" "ON"
"slave_transaction_retries" "10"
"slave_type_conversions"    ""
"slow_launch_time"  "2"
"slow_query_log"    "OFF"
"slow_query_log_always_write_time"  "10.000000"
"slow_query_log_use_global_control" ""
"socket"    "/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
"sort_buffer_size"  "8388608"
"sql_auto_is_null"  "OFF"
"sql_big_selects"   "ON"
"sql_buffer_result" "OFF"
"sql_log_off"   "OFF"
"sql_mode"  ""
"sql_notes" "ON"
"sql_quote_show_create" "ON"
"sql_safe_updates"  "OFF"
"sql_select_limit"  "18446744073709551615"
"sql_slave_skip_counter"    "0"
"sql_warnings"  "OFF"
"stored_program_cache"  "256"
"super_read_only"   "OFF"
"sync_binlog"   "1"
"sync_frm"  "ON"
"sync_master_info"  "10000"
"sync_relay_log"    "10000"
"sync_relay_log_info"   "10000"
"table_definition_cache"    "1636"
"table_open_cache"  "2473"
"table_open_cache_instances"    "16"
"thread_cache_size" "96"
"thread_handling"   "one-thread-per-connection"
"thread_pool_high_prio_mode"    "transactions"
"thread_pool_high_prio_tickets" "4294967295"
"thread_pool_idle_timeout"  "60"
"thread_pool_max_threads"   "100000"
"thread_pool_oversubscribe" "3"
"thread_pool_size"  "2"
"thread_pool_stall_limit"   "500"
"thread_stack"  "131072"
"thread_statistics" "OFF"
"time_format"   "%H:%i:%s"
"time_zone" "SYSTEM"
"tls_version"   "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
"tmp_table_size"    "134217728"
"tmpdir"    "/tmp"
"transaction_alloc_block_size"  "8192"
"transaction_isolation" "READ-COMMITTED"
"transaction_prealloc_size" "4096"
"transaction_read_only" "OFF"
"transaction_write_set_extraction"  "OFF"
"tx_isolation"  "READ-COMMITTED"
"tx_read_only"  "OFF"
"unique_checks" "ON"
"updatable_views_with_limit"    "YES"
"userstat"  "OFF"
"version"   "5.7.34-37"
"version_comment"   "Percona Server (GPL), Release 37, Revision 7c516e9"
"version_compile_machine"   "x86_64"
"version_compile_os"    "Linux"
"version_suffix"    ""
"wait_timeout"  "28800"
```

who can tell what parameters of Percona 5.7 need to be changed to speed up the request.

Comment: I have a feeling that that query is doing something simple, but it is written in a very complex way.  Please describe, in English, the purpose.  Something like "Un-delate the row with name=B".  (But I don't understand what "A" has to do with it.)

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE...`.  (Do that on each version if possible.)